# SalesChannelContextFactory creates context without RuleIds

Tags: shopware, shopware6

I have some code which is executed via cli command and creates orders and sends confirmation mail. Therefor the order bound sales channel rule ids need to be considered. So I'm creating a Saleschannelcontext with the SalesChannelContextFactory given and used by Shopware.

$salesChannelContext = $this->salesChannelContextFactory->create(
'',
$salesChannelEntity->getId(),
[SalesChannelContextService::LANGUAGE_ID => $salesChannelEntity->getLanguageId()]
);

But this created salesChannelContext doesn't contain any configured ruleIds. Do I need to load these manually or is there some way to tell the factory that this created context should contain rules?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to inject `Shopware\Core\Checkout\Cart\CartRuleLoader` and call `loadByToken`. This will hydrate the array of rule IDs. You may also call `loadByCart` if you want to consider rules evaluating a cart's content.

```php
$options = [
    SalesChannelContextService::LANGUAGE_ID => $languageId,
    SalesChannelContextService::CUSTOMER_ID => $customerId,
    SalesChannelContextService::CUSTOMER_GROUP_ID => $groupId,
];

$token = Uuid::randomHex();
$salesChannelContext = $this->factory->create(
    $token,
    $salesChannelId,
    $options
);

$this->cartRuleLoader->loadByToken($salesChannelContext, $token);
```

If your starting point is an existing order it might also be more practical to inject `Shopware\Core\System\SalesChannel\Context\SalesChannelContextRestorer` and use that service to restore and return a `SalesChannelContext` built from an existing order. This instance will also include the rule IDs:

```php
$salesChannelContext = $this->salesChannelContextRestorer->restoreByOrder($orderId, $context);
```

Comment: Thanks @dneustadt, your answer looks reasonable, but in my env `loadByToken()` method as well as `loadByCard()` leads to the `OutOfMemory` issue. Code analysis shows that problem is related to the `CardRuleLoader::load()` method. It profiles the 'cart-rule-loader' process which is actually not needed. Is it good enough to inject `Shopware\Core\Checkout\Cart\AbstractCartPersister` and use `$cart = $this->cartPersister->load($cartToken, $context);` ? or I will miss something with that solution?